# How to update apps in Android things?

Tags: android, android-things, ota

I'm new in Android Things and was trying to do OTA updates. In Android things console whenever I pushed a new OTA, along with the new app version, it refreshed the image as well. However, I want my image to be the same as earlier and just app to get replaced over the air. Is it possible?.
I have been thinking to use play store to update my app in android things. Can it be done?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Things, all apps on the system are bundled in an updated OTA image and updated in that way. There's no mechanism for updating individual applications like on Google Play.

Comment: Felkar so, what should I do to update only the app. Is there a no solution for it?

Comment: You will have to create a new OTA image with the updated app.